# Enum in header files

Tags: c++, enums, header, scope

I have enum declared in a header file called "sm.h"

```
enum GameStates
{
  STATE_NULL = 0,
  STATE_INTRO,
  STATE_TITLE,
  STATE_MAIN,
  STATE_EXIT
};
```

All it does is list the possible game states

However in the following line in "base.cpp":

```
stateID = STATE_INTRO;
```

The compiler says "STATE_INTRO was not declared in this scope". I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I know that I have included the header file right and I can go to its deceleration from the .cpp file. So why am I getting this error.

```
stateID = STATE_INTRO;
```

Is used in:

```
bool baseFunctions::load_rc()
{
 stateID = STATE_INTRO;

 currentState = new Intro();

 return true;
}
```

which defines a class function in a header file.

There are no global conflicts because it is the only enum in the whole program

Comment: Are they in the same namespace?

Comment: I am not using a name space. Do I need a namespace

Comment: I thought that you did not need a namespace qualification

Comment: Would be useful if you could post more complete code. These pieces on their own don't appear to be incorrect, so something must be wrong at a different level in your code.

Comment: Sorry, should be more explicit. A lot of people here are really good programmers that can take 6 lines of code and figure out that hey, you're getting conflicts in the global namespace or some jazz like that. But for the rest of us mere mortals we often like to have compilable, testable code so that we can poke it and prod it until it works. At a minimum you might want to give the header including the enumeration declaration and the `load_rc()` function.

Comment: Sorry I will add all of the base.cpp, base.h, sm.cpp, cm.h

Comment: @Michael no matter how good a programmer you are, you can't figure out what's wrong from this code except what people have guessed above

Comment: @drCoding Sorry, didn't mean to rant and rave at you. There's some misplaced anger towards current emails in my queue in that last message.

Comment: I did fell like looking for a upload site so I used my web server. www.thedigsutdio/code has base.cpp,base.h, and sm.h.

Comment: @drCoding Is the enumeration declared in a difference class than baseFunctions? If that's the case you need to prefix `STATE_INTRO` with the name of the class it resides in. For instance `<class>::STATE_INTRO`

Comment: In sm.h near the top is the enumeration. The enumeration is global because it will be need in other files.

Comment: The URL for your site seems incorrect. It doesn't even have a top-level domain.

Comment: sorry typed it in wrong http://www.thedigstudio.com/code/

Comment: @drCoding It's never a good idea to put anything in the global namespace that isn't an absolute necessity - this can cause naming conflicts. It's much better to define a namespace for your application instead. For instance `namespace app{ /*class, struct and enum declarations go here*/ }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your link to your files, you have the following in both `sm.h` and `base.h`

```
#ifndef BASE_H_INCLUDED
#define BASE_H_INCLUDED
```

Change the one in `sm.h` to something like

```
#ifndef SM_H_INCLUDED
#define SM_H_INCLUDED
```

and I expect you'll be fine.

As it is, `base.cpp` loads `base.h`, then when it gets to `sm.h` the #ifndef is false, so it excludes everything in `sm.h`.

Comment: Not a problem. If your compiler supports `#pragma once`, you can use it in place of your `#ifndef`s. Code will be less portable, though.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is that you aren't including "sm.h" in base.cpp

Comment: sm.h is included in base.cpp and base.h